# Allow user to order the layout

Tags: wpf, layout

I create a window with grid Including 2 stackpanel with controls.
I want to allow the user to change the layout in real time.
for example to switch between the 2 stackpanels that the lower will be in the top And vice versa.

I have also window with tabs and I want to allow the user to take one tab and drag it that it will be like a floating window.

thank you!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I want to know where can If find info about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 2 rows in the `Grid` - one for each `StackPanel`. Then at runtime call this code to reorder.

`Grid.SetRow(myStack, 1);`

As for the tabs, try http://dragablz.net/

Comment: Thank you, you have helped me!

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer if it worked for you.